# Cross-compiling libsodium for iOS

Tags: ios, compilation, cross-compiling, armv7, libsodium

I want to cross-compile the libsodium cryptography library for use on iOS. Specifically, I want to compile it for armv7, armv7s and arm64 so that it works for older as well as newer iPhones.

I followed the instructions on the libsodium website (https://download.libsodium.org/doc/installation/index.html) to cross-compile it and ran the configure script like this:

```
./configure --host=armv7-apple-darwin
```

and the same for armv7s-apple-darwin and armv8-apple-darwin (which is the same as arm64 I think/hope, since arm64 wasn't supported). Then I did "make install" which succeeded without errors. However, if I then inspected the created static library:

```
lipo -info libsodium.a
```

it tells me:

```
Non-fat file: libsodium.a is architecture: x86_64
```

for all of these. Why is this static library targeted towards x86_64 architectures while I targeted the armv7, armv7s, armv8 architectures? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the build script [available in the source repository](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/blob/master/dist-build/ios.sh).

Alternatively, pre-built libraries are available [in the Swift bindings](https://github.com/jedisct1/swift-sodium/blob/master/Sodium/libsodium-ios.a).